# Verify that the following set is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I would like to check that the following set is a subspace:

$$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:z=0,xy\geq0\}$$

To do so, I need to check for three conditions: non-emptiness, closure under addition and closure under scalar multiplication.

It is easy to see that $(0,0,0)$ belongs to the set, so the first condition is verified. Then, I proceed to check for closure under addition by considering generic vectors $u=(a,b,c)$ and $v=(d, e,f)$. We have:

$$(a,b,c)+(d,e,f)=(a+d,b+e,c+f)$$

$(a+d)(b+e)\ge0$ isn't necessarily true? I'm not too sure about this part.

To check for scalar multiplication I'm going to assume there exists a generic vector $v=(a,b,c)$ and a scalar $m$ so that the product $mv \in S$.

$$m(a,b,c)=(ma,mb,mc)$$

We have

$$(ma)(mb)\ge0\rightarrow m^2(ab)\ge0$$

which should be true for all $m$. Therefore this should be a subspace, however, my textbook says it's not. Any hints on why?

Comment: Since z=0 for the set, isn't it equivalent to the set $$ S={(x,y)|xy \gt 0 $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the first part. You should check if $(a+d)(b+e) \geq 0$ (this is the condition to a sum lie or not Iin that set since $z=0$ will always hold), not what you did. $(-4, 0, 0) + (2, 1, 0) = (-2, 1, 0) \not \in S$, but the first ones do.

Also, you could think geometrically. $S$ is the region enclosed by both positive $xy$ axes $\cup$ both negative $xy$ axes. Every proper subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ looks either like a plane or a line, and certainly $S$ doesn’t look like that.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Let $u=(1,0,0), v=(0,-1,0)$. Then $u,v \in S$. Does $u+v \in S$?

Answer (score 2):

**Geometric intuition**

Let's look at $S$. Since we have the condition $z=0$, it is contained in the subspace generated by $i :=(1,0,0)$ and $j :=(0,1,0)$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. We will now consider $S$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ for commodity.

A vector $s=(x,y)$ belongs to $S$ if, and only if, $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. If one plots $S$, $S$ will be the union of the upper right and lower left quadrangles.

This means that $S$ is neither

- a subspace of dimension $0$ (the singleton $\{0\}$)
- a subspace of dimension $1$ (a line)
- a subspace of dimension $2$ (the whole $\mathbb{R}^2$)

**How to prove this?**

To be a subspace, $S$ should be closed under addition. Your task is to find $s,s' \in S$, say $s=(x,y,0)$ and $s'=(x',y',0)$, such that $s+s'\notin S$.
**Hint :** take $y=1$ and $y'=-2$.